# I want to use different color and font family for each char value of React-Native TextInput

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

**My code:**

```
export default class ClearComponent extends Component {


    color= ['red', 'blue']
    font_family= ['normal', 'notoserif', 'sans-serif']
    state = {
    text: '',
    context: [
      
    ],
    color:"black",
    font_family:"normal",
  };

  textInputOnChange = (text) => {
    const {context, color, font_family} = this.state;
    
    if (context.length > text.length) {
        
        context.pop()
       this.setState({
            context


       })
      
    } else {
        this.setState({
            context:[...context,{
                value: text[text.length - 1],
                color,
                font_family
              }]
        })
      
      
    }
  };
 

  render() {
    const {context} = this.state;
    const { color, font_family} =  this
    return (
      
      <View>
        <TextInput  onChangeText={this.textInputOnChange}>
          {context.map((element) => {
              
            return (
              <Text
                style={{fontFamily: element.font_family, color: element.color,fontSize:25}}>
                {element.value}
              </Text>
            );
          })}
        </TextInput>
        <Picker
        selectedValue={this.state.font_family}
        mode="dropdown"
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
            this.setState({font_family: itemValue});
          }}
        >
          {font_family.map((element) => {
            return (
              <Picker.Item
                key={(key) => key.id}
                value={element}
                label={element}
              />
            );
          })}
        </Picker>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          {color.map((element) => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
                  this.setState({color:element}) 
                  console.log(this)}}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    height: 25,
                    width: 25,
                    
                    backgroundColor: element,
                    borderRadius: 20,
                    marginHorizontal: 2,
                    marginVertical: 2,
                  }}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          })}
        </View>
        <Text style={{fontFamily:"",fontSize:40}}>dsadas</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I am working on a notebook application. I have also encountered such problem, I found a few solutions but it was not enough and it brings up a lot of problems.

I want to make a different style definition for each character, but this code works badly.

Are there special libraries for this?

I am open to your alternative solutions.

Comment: please describe what is your problem with current implementation

Comment: I want to assign style for each char value, this is partly done in this application, but when the char values ​​are deleted from the beginning, the program gives logically different results. is there any other method of this process?